# Deploying a spring web service or another framework web service on the Oracle Service Bus

Tags: web-services, weblogic11g, osb, oracle-service-bus

I am creating a web service in spring or other web service framework. Can I deploy it directly on the weblogic server that comes with the OSB? or do I need to deploy it on another weblogic instance.

The reason I am asking is the OSB weblogic has a lot of OSB specific deployment jars/wars - ALSB*jar, DBAdapter*rar, etc etc.

I hate to deploy the spring web service next to these, not sure if it is a best practice. Please let me know.

PS: Eventually, I am planning to wrap this service with a proxy/business or do a web service call out to this internal web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy on the same weblogic instance or create a new domain and deploy it on that domain.

Comment: Thank you. Wondering what the best practice is? Is the weblogic instance that comes with the OSB purely for OSB web services only?

Comment: Not really. You can add other applications as well. But I would prefer separation of concerns if feasible.